# How to read headers in body/response promise

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, response-headers

I'm calling API endpoint using `fetch API`.
How can I read response **body** and **headers** in resolved body promise?

My code snippet below:

```
  fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      // How to access response headers here?
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

As described in the Fetch API [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#headers), you can get response headers with this snippet:

```js
fetch(myRequest)
  .then((response) => {
     const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
     if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) {
       throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
     }
     return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
      /* process your data further */
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

For the **body** you will find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) some examples.

Comment: I need to get headers where I process my JSON.

Comment: In my example you can reach contentType in your json method

Comment: `response.headers.get("content-type")` - this helped, thanks.